# Add Inline Style to Visible Last Child

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm using:

```
$( ".scroll > *:visible:last" ).css( "margin-bottom", "0" );
```

to target all visible children and add "margin-bottom: 0" (inline) to the last visible child, and it produces this result:

```
<div class="scroll">

    <p>This is text...</p>
    <p>This is text...</p>
    <p>This is text...</p>
    <p>This is text...</p>
    <p>This is text...</p>
    <p>This is text...</p>
    <p>This is text...</p>
    <div style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
        <p>fsfdsfsdfsd</p>
    </div>
    <p class="hide">This is text...</p>
    <p class="hide">This is text...</p>
    <p class="hide">This is text...</p>

</div>
```

this is as expected and works fine until the class "scroll" is the last visible child, like so:

```
<div class="scroll">

    <p>This is text...</p>
    <p>This is text...</p>
    <p>This is text...</p>
    <p>This is text...</p>
    <p>This is text...</p>
    <p>This is text...</p>
    <p>This is text...</p>
    <div class="scroll">
        <p>fsfdsfsdfsd</p>
    </div>
    <p class="hide">This is text...</p>
    <p class="hide">This is text...</p>
    <p class="hide">This is text...</p>

</div>
```

the inline styles now get added like this:

```
<div class="scroll">

    <p>This is text...</p>
    <p>This is text...</p>
    <p>This is text...</p>
    <p>This is text...</p>
    <p>This is text...</p>
    <p>This is text...</p>
    <p>This is text...</p>
    <div class="scroll">
        <p style="margin-bottom: 0px;">fsfdsfsdfsd</p>
    </div>
    <p class="hide">This is text...</p>
    <p class="hide">This is text...</p>
    <p class="hide">This is text...</p>

</div>
```

I think I would expect this:

```
<div class="scroll">

    <p>This is text...</p>
    <p>This is text...</p>
    <p>This is text...</p>
    <p>This is text...</p>
    <p>This is text...</p>
    <p>This is text...</p>
    <p>This is text...</p>
    <div class="scroll" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
        <p style="margin-bottom: 0px;">fsfdsfsdfsd</p>
    </div>
    <p class="hide">This is text...</p>
    <p class="hide">This is text...</p>
    <p class="hide">This is text...</p>

</div>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just should use `last-of-type` instead of `last`

> The :last-of-type selector matches every element that is the last
>   child, of a particular type, of its parent.

```js
$(".scroll > *:visible:last-of-type").css("margin-bottom", "0");
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroll">

  <p>This is text...</p>
  <p>This is text...</p>
  <p>This is text...</p>
  <p>This is text...</p>
  <p>This is text...</p>
  <p>This is text...</p>
  <p>This is text...</p>
  <div class="scroll">
    <p>fsfdsfsdfsd</p>
  </div>
  <p class="hide">This is text...</p>
  <p class="hide">This is text...</p>
  <p class="hide">This is text...</p>

</div>
```